# interactive correlation heatmap in shiny

Tags: shiny, heatmap

I want to reproduce the example at: https://scip.shinyapps.io/scip_app/

Basically, I have a 300 by 300 adjusted correlation matrix and a 300 by 300 unadjusted correlation matrix and want to show them interactively with zoom in and zoom out function. The text descriptions should display the point estimates and confidence intervals.

Is there any template I can quickly refer to?

Comment: You could try ggheatmap? There are a few question on SO about it that you could use.

Comment: Google "heatmap" and "R" and look at images. What you want is close enough to a heatmap that most people will call it that.

Comment: I can easily reproduce the heatmap but what I want is the zoom-in function as it is a huge correlation matrix. Did you look at the shiny example?

Comment: Yes, a bit. But if you want zoom-in you could have a look at plotly. https://plot.ly/r/heatmaps/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on the data from Mike, you can use the `d3heatmap` library

```
library(d3heatmap)
library(shiny)
n1 <- 100
n2 <- 100
nr <- 30
nc <- 30
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(rnorm(n1), nrow=nr, ncol=nc)
y <- matrix(rnorm(n2), nrow=nr, ncol=nc)
MAT <- cor(x,y)
ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    d3heatmapOutput("heatmap", width = "100%", height="600px")
  )
)

## server.R
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$heatmap <- renderD3heatmap({d3heatmap(MAT)})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

**Edit:** Specify the colours if needs to be and display the data as is, note that `Colv = T` by default, which means it will group the correlated items together

```
output$heatmap <- renderD3heatmap({d3heatmap(MAT, colors = "Blues", Colv = FALSE)})
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. I didn't notice he wanted a Shiny example... But what are the numbers and the hierarchy in that diagram? Do they come automatically with a `cor()` output?

Comment: @MikeWise, I added the appropriate colours and removed the ordering which was present `Colv = F`. It groups them by default

Comment: Odd he didn't upvote you. Great answer - will remember that function. In fact I think I can use it soon...

Comment: Is there some function which help in linking our heatmap to another graph or data. Like if i click at a particular place in heatmap it outputs details of that particular box in a new place. Like a company master or something?

Comment: @rahulyadav click means zoom out, so right now its not available, if you want this functionality, refer to this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/f5umHq7U1zc

Comment: https://plot.ly/r/shiny-coupled-events/ or https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/plot-interaction-advanced.html may also work. I found out later abut these.

Answer (score 2):

I think plotly can do this well. Here are the docs [https://plot.ly/r/heatmaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5w1i.png)/:

And here is a little template-example (returning Porkchop's favor by borrowing his minimal shiny template) with some fake data:

```
library(shiny)
n1 <- 100
n2 <- 100
nr <- 30
nc <- 30
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(rnorm(n1), nrow=nr, ncol=nc)
y <- matrix(rnorm(n2), nrow=nr, ncol=nc)
cmat <- cor(x,y)
plot_ly(z = cmat, type = "heatmap")
ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput("heatmap", width = "100%", height="600px")
  )
)

## server.R
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$heatmap <- renderPlotly({plot_ly(z = cmat, type = "heatmap")})
}
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Here is the Shiny output. Note it is fully zoomable:

[image]

Comment: Is there some function which help in linking our heatmap to another graph or data. Like if i click at a particular place in heatmap it outputs details of that particular box in a new place. Like a company master or something?